# node.js: How to look up an API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am a new practicer of Node.js. I have a pretty silly problem. When I use packages or some code written by other people, I cannot find out where the definitions of components. Right now, I am struggling for searching for *request.files* used in Express.js. My questions are, if I don't study the source:

1. Where should I go to see the formal API document on *request.files*?
2. How should I identify the type of a *req* object: http.request or expressjs.request?
3. What are optimal ways to find an API's definition?

Comment: `req.files` doesn't exist unless you add [middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) adding this functionality, which will be why you can't find it in the docs.

Comment: @BenFortune so it's related to my third quest :-)

Answer (score 0):

Express has pretty good documentation. Take a look at what the [request object has by default](http://expressjs.com/api.html#request). This of course can be modified by middleware. In this case, you're looking for req.files, which could be added by a few different middleware. A Google search for `express req.files` shows [expressjs/multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) as the fourth result. Taking a look at that we see:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')

var app = express()
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}))
```

You can access the fields and files in the request object:

```
console.log(req.body)
console.log(req.files)
```

So in this case, the multer middleware will add the ability to handle uploaded files, and make those files available at `req.files`.